# Version compatible?

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

Whether retrofit 2.9.0 can compatible okhttp3 version higher than 3.14.9 or not?

```
retrofit 2.9.0 -> okhttp3:3.14.9
sentry 5.7.3 -> okhttp3:4.9.2
last input okhttp3:4.9.2 + sentry 5.7.3 + retrofit 2.9.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/discussions/3593